# Can't bind to 'index' when using ngFor loop Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ngfor

I have the following error appear when I try passing the `index` of a `*ngFor` loop through into a component.

*Can't bind to 'count' since it isn't a known property of 'app-details'*

It seams I can't pass the index through.

---

**First file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { App } from 'reg.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'reg',
  styleUrls:['reg.component.scss'],
  template:`
    <div class="container">
    <div class="col-6">
      <h2>App Details:</h2>
      <app-details *ngFor="let app of apps; let i = index;"
        [details]="app"
        [count]="i"
      </app-details>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})

export class RegComponent {
 apps: App[];
}
```

---

**Second file**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { App } from 'reg.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  template: `
  <div class="col-12">
      <span>Index: {{ details | json }}</span>
      <span>Index: {{ count }}</span>
  </div>
  `
})
export class AppDetailsComponent {
  @Input()
  app: App;
  count: number;
}
```

---

**reg.interface**

```
export interface App {
  type: string,
  price: number
}
```

I'm importing the `BrowserModule` + `CommonModule` in my main app.module

Any help much appreciated - I can always add more details to the question etc if required. Thanks

Comment: App-details selector should be `app-details` and not `<app-details></app-details>`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the note - I've changed that but still get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export class AppDetailsComponent {
  @Input() app: App;
  @Input() count: number;
}
```

Comment: Boom! Nice one! A new input for every input..! Can't believe I missed that one!